# Prestashop Web service to return JSON

Tags: php, web-services, json, prestashop

After extensive search over internet i am sure that Prestashop does not return data in JSON format, it only returns in XML format (which leads to cross domain accessing issue unfortunately).

Now, I am trying to convert XML(returned by Prestashop) to JSON. I want to write php code which could take XML from web service and sent back JSON. For this purpose i tried many tutorial but in vain. The converted JSON does not have value in it, so is useless.
The methods i tried are listed below.

http://www.sitepoint.com/php-xml-to-json-proxy/
[PHP convert XML to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830599/php-convert-xml-to-json)

**XML to convert:**

```
<name>
<language id="1" xlink:href="http://localhost/prestashop/api/languages/1">
<![CDATA[ iPod Nano ]]>
</language>
</name>
```

**Returned JSON:**

```
"name":{"language":{"@attributes":{"id":"1"}}}
```

Comment: I've never used the Prestashop webservice, but it may be easier to bypass the code where Prestashop creates the XML and replace it with a code where you create the json you need. This is just an idea though.

Answer (score 55):

I don't know about historical support for this, but...

In the latest version of Prestashop (currently v1.6.0.9), you can get a JSON response from any WebService API request by appending `output_format=JSON` to your request query string.

E.g.
`http://example.prestashop.com/api/products?output_format=JSON`

Comment: Still works in 1.7.2, this answer should be accepted.

Comment: FYI, output_format value is case sensitive. So, if it doesn't work, make sure you use JSON instead of json.

Answer (score 2):

Using php pear "[XML_Serializer](https://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer)":

```
{
  "product": {
    "id_category_default": "XXX",
    "id_tax_rules_group": "1",
    "type": "simple",
    "id_shop_default": "1",
    "reference": "XXXXXXXX",
    "price": "XX.XXXXXX",
    "active": "1",
    "redirect_type": "404",
    "id_product_redirected": "0",
    "available_for_order": "1",
    "condition": "new",
    "show_price": "1",
    "indexed": "0",
    "visibility": "both",
    "advanced_stock_management": "0",
    "link_rewrite": {
      "language": {
        "_attributes": {
          "id": "1"
        },
        "_content": "ipod-nano"
      }
    },
    "name": {
      "language": {
        "_attributes": {
          "id": "1"
        },
        "_content": "iPod Nano"
      }
    },
    "associations": {
      "categories": {
        "category": {
          "id": "XXX"
        }
      },
      "stock_availables": {
        "stock_available": {
          "id": "XXXX",
          "id_product_attribute": "X"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**See this link**: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/602449-aporte-webservice-prestashop-16-json-request-post-y-put/#elComment_2930631

Answer (score 1):

> only add ?output_format=JSON end url

http://example.com/api/products?output_format=JSON

Answer (score -1):

Prestashop has die(Tools::jsonEncode([Associative Array])) for ajax return or just remove die for non ajax return.