# Is it possible to update products with Prestashop web service in JSON format?

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am having difficulties updating categories associated to a product with their web service. I have read in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831487/prestashop-web-service-to-return-json) that is possible to get a JSON response.

I wonder if you can update the product using this format (it seems that nobody wonders it, because I cannot find how to).
Prestashop doc does not even talk about the JSON format...

So, does anybody knows how to do it, or should I start searching how to build my own prestashop component to sync data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **retrieve** data you can append `?output_format=JSON` to your web service URL to let Prestashop return data in JSON instead of the default XML format.

```
http://www.myprestashop.com/api/products?output_format=JSON
```

To **update** data Prestashop Web service uses XML. If you want to use JSON, you need to modify Webservice and convert JSON to XML or directly JSON to data.

Comment: Yep that is how Prestashop returns you data in JSON, I said that I already know that. I was asking about the possibility of sending to Prestashop data in JSON format in order to update or create items.

Comment: You can send in JSON, but sure you need more code modifications.

Comment: what do you mean with that? That you have to do more modifications if you compare it with XML format and you don't know what modifications are needed? Or that does not make sense to do it, since you have to do more modifications and means more processing cost?

Comment: Prestashop Web service uses XML. http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Web+service+one-page+documentation#Webserviceone-pagedocumentation-Creatingandadding If you want to use JSON, you need to modify Webservice and convert JSON to XML or directly JSON to data.

Comment: So the answer is "no"? You can only retrieve data in JSON format but is not prepared to insert/update data in that format?

Comment: Hmm, I think you should update your answer then, so I can check it as the answer.