# Formatting XML in to JSON with PHP

Tags: php, xml, json

I am attempting to get a JSON feed output from attributes of an XML feed. I can get the data out of the XML, however, I am unable to get it to format correctly. The error seems to be with the `json_encode` not adding the curly braces to the outputted date. This is the code I have so far:

```
<?php

    $url = 'http://cloud.tfl.gov.uk/TrackerNet/LineStatus';

    if(!$xml = simplexml_load_file($url))
    {
        die("No xml for you");
    }

    $linestatus = array();

    foreach ($xml->LineStatus as $line)
    {
        echo $line->Line['Name'];
        echo $line->Status['Description'];
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    print_r(json_encode($linestatus));

?>
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830599/php-convert-xml-to-json?rq=1

Comment: don't use `print_r()` for the JSON string; plain old `print` or `echo` is what you need.

Comment: also, I don't see your code actually using `$linestatus` anywhere. Maybe you meant to do something with it inside the `foreach()` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not storing the name and description into the array.

Try this:

```
foreach ($xml->LineStatus as $line)
{
    $linestatus[] =  array('name' => $line->Line['Name']);
    $linestatus[] =  array('description' => $line->Line['Description']);
}
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QRKg6N)

Comment: That would split the line data rather than grouping it.

Comment: @cillosis: See the demo. :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure Name and Description are associated. This means together they make up a single line and hence should be grouped together with a `$linestatus[] = $line->Line` statement.

Comment: This is the closest to what I am trying to achieve. But then when I want to call on the outputted JSON, I am then getting undefined when I try to access with JQuery 'value.name', for example.

Comment: I also notice that it outputs the JSON with the station name's identifier as '0', is there a way to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

The `echo`s are screwing everything up.  I think you intend to append to `linestatus` which remains empty per your code.

```
$linestatus[] = array(
    "name" => $line->Line['Name'],
    "description" => $line->Status['Description']
);
```

You also need to use `echo` instead of `print_r` to actually emit the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `$linestatus` as an array, then never put anything in it before finally encoding it and trying to output it. Of course it won't work as expected! Instead, you should be populating it with values:

```
$linestatus = array();

foreach ($xml->LineStatus as $line)
{
    $linestatus[] = $line->Line;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
print_r(json_encode($linestatus));
```