# trouble parsing xml and converting it to json with php for use with $.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml

I'm attempting to use php to grab xml from an API. So far I've looked at the following [blog post](http://lostechies.com/seanbiefeld/2011/10/21/simple-xml-to-json-with-php/) and [this previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830599/php-convert-xml-to-json) stackoverflow post but am not having success.

The xml data is available [here](http://api.wefeelfine.org:8080/ShowFeelings?display=xml&returnfields=imageid,feeling,sentence,posttime,postdate,posturl,gender,born,country,state,city,lat,lon,conditions&city=detroit&limit=500) by viewing the source of the web page.

From my understanding php's `json_encode` returns the json data as string prepended by `string(length)`.

What I'd like to do is to load the encoded json data with JQuery's `$.ajax` to manipulate the data with javascript. However the data returned from php's `json_encode` is not compatible with `$.ajax`.

Would anyone have any suggestions on how to format the string so that the data can be read by ajax?

update, my code php code is here:

```
<?php        

    $url = file_get_contents("http://api.wefeelfine.org:8080/ShowFeelings?display=xml&returnfields=sentence&limit=50");

    $simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($url);

    $json = json_encode($simpleXml);

    var_dump($json);

?>
```

I'm using php to do a cross-domain request, then using the url for the php code with $.ajax. When using $.ajax to access the API's url without php I get a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` error.

Comment: are you parsing your ajax response text through JSON.parse()?

Comment: that xml is fairly simple to parse using ajax also if you are having problems converting it to json. Need to show your php code

Comment: json_encode shouldn't prepend 'string(length)', or anything not in the origin object.  If I were to guess that's just the output of a var_dump or print_r describing the result of a json_encode operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_encode` won't work on a `SimpleXMLElement` object, at least not as you would expect it. Try preprocessing your XML like so:

```
$feelings = array();
foreach($simpleXml as $feeling) {
    $feelings[] = array('sentence' => $feeling['sentence'] . '');
}
$json = json_encode($feelings);
```

Comment: thanks Samy. Looks like that works! Though I realized that the data I'd like contains multiple tags where as the url above only has a single tag (sentence). Is there a way I could return multiple tags? For example in [this url](http://api.wefeelfine.org:8080/ShowFeelings?display=xml&returnfields=imageid,feeling,sentence,posttime,postdate,posturl,gender,born,country,state,city,lat,lon,conditions&limit=500)