# jQuery - each() not working with multiple div same ID

Tags: jquery, each

I using `each()` but only return the contents of first element...

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/UserNaN/L8pA5/

How to get all the contents with div have same ID is `#title`

Please help me!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select all elements with a particular ID in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902839/how-to-select-all-elements-with-a-particular-id-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Never** use same ID for multiple elements. ID has to be unique of course. For your purposes you should use classes

So:

1. Remove ID "title" from all the elements and move it to the class property: `<div class='title active' data='1'>`
2. Use ".title" as selector `$('#container').find('.title').each(...`

http://jsfiddle.net/L8pA5/1/

Answer (score 2):

It will surely fail since ids have to be unique.

Use classes instead. You've already set `active` class to the `div`.

So, you can do:

```
$('.active').each()
```

Comment: @UserNaN but you didn't accept mine? Anyway glad to have helped

Comment: I'm sorry if my actions do you not happy... I want to solve the problem from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424324/how-to-convert-html-contents-to-json-using-php), but doesn't seem to have any answers can help me. Therefore, I have to "solve" from the client, and the answer from @pumpkinzzz is more obvious. If you do not feel upset, please see [my previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424324/how-to-convert-html-contents-to-json-using-php), thanks!

Comment: @UserNaN its not that I'm unhappy or something like that. I answered it first so, just asked. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

use `$("div#title").each(function(){});`

I was facing same problem. Its working for me.