# HTML code to JSON with help of php

Tags: php, html, json, wordpress, angularjs

hope you can help me solve a little problem.

*i saw this post but still got some errors : [How to convert HTML to JSON using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062537/how-to-convert-html-to-json-using-php)*

I created a PHP file which fetches a post from wordpress with this format

```
<h1><img src="category1.jpg" />Category 1</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>some text.<strong><em>AUTHOR 1</em></strong></li>
    <li>some other text.<strong><em>AUTHOR 2</em></strong></li>
    <li>some othe other text.<strong><em>AUTHOR 3</em></strong></li>
  </ul>
<h1><img src="category2.jpg" />Category 2</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>some new text.<strong><em>AUTHOR 4</em></strong></li>
    <li>some other new text.<strong><em>AUTHOR 5</em></strong></li>
    <li>some othe other new text.<strong><em>AUTHOR 6</em></strong></li>
  </ul>
```

what I am trying to achieve is json object looks like this:

```
[
  { 
    category: "Category 1", content: [
                                      {text: "some text.", author:"AUTHOR 1"},
                                      {text: "some other text.", author:"AUTHOR 2"},
                                      {text: "some other other text.", author:"AUTHOR 3"},
                                     ]
  },
  { 
    category: "Category 2", content: [
                                      {text: "some new text.", author:"AUTHOR 4"},
                                      {text: "some other new text.", author:"AUTHOR 5"},
                                      {text: "some other other new text.", author:"AUTHOR 6"},
                                     ]
  }
```

i need to use it for Angular modules afterwards.

is there any solution for this? any function?

many thanks!

Comment: There's nothing in the markup to suggest that a given note contains the author, or category information. The only thing we _could_ do is _Assume_ that the contents of a h1 tag is a category name, and the value of a `li > strong > em` is the author, but such assumptions are extremely risky. Also: show us what you've tried!

Comment: thank you very much!
let's say i can live with those assumptions, you say there is no PHP existing function that does something similar to the result i wanted?

i have tried json_encode() on the very long string and seems that i get the same long string as an output.

also i have tried what is suggested in the answers here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062537/how-to-convert-html-to-json-using-php

which got me a little step further but still got some errors of "invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: I'd suggest looking into Regular Expressions to match the various patterns you are after. This would be a little fiddly, and involve various loops but should be doable.

Comment: yeah, thanks! i thought i could somehow avoid using it, but if i'll have to i'll use it.

Comment: @Novocaine: ***Don't use regex on a DOM*** parse the markup, extract the nodes you need, and use their values when constructing an array, nice and easy _and_ reliable.

Comment: @DimaGimburg: No, don't. Regex + markup = evil. look into `DOMDocument` and/or `SimpleXMLElement` (on php.net). parse the DOM, and set to work

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem what's so wrong with regex on markup? Is it because it's not particularly reliable, or is that only one reason?

Comment: It's a simple matter of grammar hierarchy: Regex is (as the name suggests) restricted to _regular grammars_, markup is too complex for it: They're context-free grammars, so regex isn't the right tool for the job

Comment: @eliasVanOotegem thank you very much! i think DOMDocument is what i searched for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Once you've converted the document to xml, you can treat it as an array and do a foreach on all  elements. SimpleXML also allows you to treat elements as arrays. After separating the information, use json_encode() to build your JSON object. Below is an easy way to import the html code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument ();

if (! $doc->loadHTML ( $html )) //this should contain the html code from the page

$page = simplexml_import_dom ( $doc );

//do something with $page
```

Alternatively, there are quite a few libraries and frameworks that do this for you. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) for more info.

Comment: @DimaGimburg: SimpleXML isn't always installed mind you, `DOMDocument` still is the extension with the widest support (last time I checked). Besides, it's really easy to do what you need to do here [Fully working example](https://eval.in/204181)

Comment: thanks @EliasVanOotegem this is exactly what i talked about. of course ill manipulate it to work my way ;)