# Retrieving data from html file as JSON object in Angular js

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

what i'm trying to do is getting data from an html file and i want the output to be a json object in angularjs i'm not quite sure if this is possible or not .

so for example i have this html file test.html

```
<my-tag type='text' size='14' default='header' label='Header1' />
<my-tag type='textarea' size='50' default='paragraph' label='Text1'/>
```

i need a function that call this html file and it returns json object like

```
[
    { label:'Header1', type: 'text', default:'header', size: '14'},
    { label:'Text1', type:'textarea',default:'paragraph', size: '50'}
];
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-to-json

Comment: but i want it to return an object a variable not a file

Comment: and I can't really get it work on my angularjs app

Comment: JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980648/map-html-to-json. PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062537/how-to-convert-html-to-json-using-php

Comment: Great that helps so much