# convert html into json in the form scraping php

Tags: php, json, web-scraping

This html  structure comes from some other url and we need to extract using file get content or using curl

[image]

```
The <div> structure shown above in the image.
What i want to do is convert this <div> structure into a json encode structure.
But in json array structure it should look like.
partition need to be made based on <h2> tag followed by their <div> tags.
eg: if first <h2> tag containes one <div> tag then <h2> tag array must contain only one sub array of <div> tag.
if <h2> tag followed by three <div> tag then <h2> tag array must contain three sub array of <div> tags.
```

Comment: What did you try and what errors did you get. Show us some code!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert HTML to JSON using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062537/how-to-convert-html-to-json-using-php)