# Get list all datatables to data array

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a display form as on image, if click button "add jadwal" automatic save to list table.

Asking : 
how to list data datatables after clicking button "submit/simpan" to be data json as this below? 
thanks

```
 {
"mapel": [
  {
    "kelas": "1",
    "hari": "Senin",
  },
  {
    "kelas": "2",
    "hari": "Senin",
  },
]
```

}

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5a52.jpg)

Comment: Please include all necessary information in the question itself, don't just post a link or an image.

Comment: I already update my question. Sorry my english bahasa not good

Comment: I got this from another post. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062537/how-to-convert-html-to-json-using-php)

Comment: No convert html to json but get all list datatables to array json

Comment: are you going to use Codeigniter-3 as you tagged in your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to obtain a DOMDocument object representing your HTML, then you just need to traverse it recursively and construct the data structure that you want.

Converting your HTML document into a DOMDocument should be as simple as this:

```
function html_to_obj($html) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    return element_to_obj($dom->documentElement);
}
```

Then, a simple traversal of $dom->documentElement which gives the kind of structure you described could look like this:

```
function element_to_obj($element) {
    $obj = array( "tag" => $element->tagName );
    foreach ($element->attributes as $attribute) {
        $obj[$attribute->name] = $attribute->value;
    }
    foreach ($element->childNodes as $subElement) {
        if ($subElement->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE) {
            $obj["html"] = $subElement->wholeText;
        }
        else {
            $obj["children"][] = element_to_obj($subElement);
        }
    }
    return $obj;
}
```

**Test case**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title> This is a test </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Is this working? </h1>  
        <ul>
            <li> Yes </li>
            <li> No </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>



header("Content-Type: text/plain");
echo json_encode(html_to_obj($html), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

**Output**

```
{
    "tag": "html",
    "lang": "en",
    "children": [
        {
            "tag": "head",
            "children": [
                {
                    "tag": "title",
                    "html": " This is a test "
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "body",
            "html": "  \n        ",
            "children": [
                {
                    "tag": "h1",
                    "html": " Is this working? "
                },
                {
                    "tag": "ul",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "tag": "li",
                            "html": " Yes "
                        },
                        {
                            "tag": "li",
                            "html": " No "
                        }
                    ],
                    "html": "\n        "
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: No convert html to json but get all list datatables to array json

Comment: Can you form the json manually by iterating through the datatables?

Comment: I can't. it's my problem. how to get all data in datatables

Comment: What is the problem? The code I have provided can also be used to read data from html controls on your form.