# parsing xml with php using json

Tags: javascript, php, xml, json

I'm building something so I can parse latitudes and longitudes from an XML file. The problem is that I have a users with multiple lat and lng (used for markers on google maps) coordinates and only the first coordinate is saved in the array. I would like to have every coordinate in the array. It looks like that the foreach function isn't working properly

Here is the ajax call to the php file where I parse the xml file. And also test if the parsed data is working with json.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>

    <script>


    $(function()
    {
        $.ajax(
            {
                type:"GET",
                url:"leesstudent.php",
                success:callback
            }
        );
    });


    function callback(data,status)
    {
        alert(data);
        var jsArr = JSON.parse(data);
        var coordinates = new Array();
        alert(jsArr[0]);
        for(var i=0;i<jsArr.length;i++)
        {
            $("#message").append("<p>" + jsArr[i].latitude + " " + jsArr[i].longitude + "</p>");
        }
    }

    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="message">
    Message..
</div>  

</body>
```

The php file where I parse the xml, from my opinion the foreach doesn't work

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("Database.xml");
$coordinaten = array();
$teller = 0;
foreach($xml->user as $item)
{
    $coordinaten[$teller]["latitude"] = (string)$item -> latitude;
    $coordinaten[$teller]["longitude"] = (string)$item -> longitude;
    $teller++;
}
print json_encode($coordinaten);
```

the xml code

```
<root>

<user>
    <username>$2y$11$6SxUsvoDGlwm3Ji6BcnzCu/QyUWNy09Ny/.M9rXIpvImgJ1igJppy</username>
    <password>$2y$11$6SxUsvoDGlwm3Ji6BcnzCu7hIhAyNKtdlui1.oMdK4gQJnkZrL/Ky</password>
    <latitude>50.74688365485319</latitude><longitude>5.0701904296875</longitude>
    <latitude>51.09662294502995</latitude><longitude>4.9713134765625</longitude>
</user>

</root>
```

I only get the first latitude and longitude data, I would like have both (and in the future even more).

Comment: Do you have a sample of the XML your PHP code is attempting to parse?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830599/php-convert-xml-to-json#answer-19391553

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreach loop isn't correct.
He will loop trough the users but never loop trough your coordinats!

```
    foreach($xml->user as $item){

    $teller = 0;
    foreach($item -> latitude as $test )
    {
         $coordinaten[$teller]["latitude"] = (string)$test;
         $teller++;
    }

    $teller = 0;

    foreach($item -> longitude as $test2)
    {
         $coordinaten[$teller]["longitude"] = (string)$test2;
         $teller++;
    }
}
```