# PHP : Convert XML Response to a specific class (Object)

Tags: php, xml, class, rest, object

I'm a Java developer. How do I deal with an XML response using PHP?

1. I would like to call a service HTTP (rest) that will return a XML.
2. After getting this XML response, I would like to convert this XML into a Object (class) automatically like I've done in Java. (That is the part I don't know to cope with).

Example:

My xml:

```
<?xml>
<root>
<user_email>fde@xxx.com</user_email>
<user_name>FDE Test</user_name>
<password_expired>false</password_expired>
</root>
```

My class:

```
class User{

    private $_userMail;
    private $_userName;
    private $_isPasswordExpired;

    // Getters and Setters

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830599/php-convert-xml-to-json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can request it with curl (and curl is not only option), [here](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2008/using-curl-and-php-to-talk-to-a-rest-service) is a simple example.

And need to change your response xml to xml object with [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

```
$response = simplexml_load_string($xml_response);
```

You can set your response data in class construct whatever you like.

```
class User {
   private $_userMail;

   function __construct($response) {
       $this->setUserMail($response->userMail);
   }

   // getters, setters
}
```

And after you get your response, you need to create User object and give your response to that.

```
// Create User
$user = new User($response);
// Check if response created a valid object
if ($user instanceof User) {
    // valid 
} else {
    // not valid 
}
```

Comment: I will try this approach and post the result here. Thanks very much!