# How to echo contents of XML but in JSON format?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, xml

I'm trying to make a webpage that echoes the contents of  http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGamesList.php?name=dog but in JSON format.

Right now my PHP page just has this code:

```
<?php 
 echo file_get_contents("http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGamesList.php?name=dog");    
?>
```

I found a JSFiddle that converts XML to JSON by using Javascript:

https://jsfiddle.net/neowot/7hfyunbc/2/

...but I'm not sure how to make it compatible with my purpose.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830599/php-convert-xml-to-json just two lines of code ;)

Comment: Tell us about the problem you're trying to solve.  It sounds more like using PHP to convert to a JSON string would be more appropriate, but you haven't told us the ultimate goal you're trying to achieve.

This sounds like an example of an XY problem  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. The answer is taken from [PHP convert XML to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830599/php-convert-xml-to-json) and slightly modified

```
$xml_string = file_get_contents("http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGamesList.php?name=dog");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```