# How to Get SOAP XML file content in to json format?

Tags: php, json, xml, curl, soap

Hello All,

I have an xml file which is SOAP xml file. Now, I want to display all the records properly. I don't have much experience in SOAP XML file. So, I want to convert it in to JSON format. So, I can display the records properly.

I have put XML file code below. I want you to check it and help me in to this.

XML Data :

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
          <SOAP:Body>
            <air:AvailabilitySearchRsp xmlns:air="http://www.travelport.com/schema/air_v29_0" xmlns:common_v29_0="http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v29_0" TraceId="trace" TransactionId="96C34B250A076478498846E5BF28A62A" ResponseTime="610" DistanceUnits="MI">
              <common_v29_0:NextResultReference>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</common_v29_0:NextResultReference>
              <air:FlightDetailsList>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAKdJUAAAAAA==" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T03:50:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T05:55:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="125" TravelTime="125" Equipment="788" OriginTerminal="3" DestinationTerminal="2"/>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAMdJUAAAAAA==" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T05:10:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T07:20:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="130" TravelTime="130" Equipment="320" OriginTerminal="1D" DestinationTerminal="1B"/>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAOdJUAAAAAA==" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T05:55:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T08:05:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="130" TravelTime="130" Equipment="320" OriginTerminal="3" DestinationTerminal="2"/>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAQdJUAAAAAA==" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T06:00:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T08:05:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="125" TravelTime="125" Equipment="320" OriginTerminal="3" DestinationTerminal="2"/>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="2ifpNy4R2BKASdJUAAAAAA==" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T06:30:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T08:35:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="125" TravelTime="125" Equipment="320" OriginTerminal="1D" DestinationTerminal="1B"/>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAUdJUAAAAAA==" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T06:35:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T08:45:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="130" TravelTime="130" Equipment="737" OriginTerminal="1D" DestinationTerminal="1"/>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAWdJUAAAAAA==" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T07:00:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T09:05:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="125" TravelTime="125" Equipment="321" OriginTerminal="3" DestinationTerminal="2"/>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAYdJUAAAAAA==" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T07:05:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T09:10:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="125" TravelTime="125" Equipment="739" OriginTerminal="3" DestinationTerminal="2"/>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAadJUAAAAAA==" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T07:05:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T09:10:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="125" TravelTime="125" Equipment="739" OriginTerminal="3" DestinationTerminal="2"/>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAcdJUAAAAAA==" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T07:30:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T09:35:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="125" TravelTime="125" Equipment="320" OriginTerminal="1D" DestinationTerminal="1B"/>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAedJUAAAAAA==" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T07:30:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T09:45:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="135" TravelTime="135" Equipment="320" OriginTerminal="3" DestinationTerminal="2"/>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAgdJUAAAAAA==" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T07:30:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T09:45:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="135" TravelTime="135" Equipment="320" OriginTerminal="3" DestinationTerminal="2"/>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAidJUAAAAAA==" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T08:00:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T10:05:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="125" TravelTime="125" Equipment="738" OriginTerminal="3" DestinationTerminal="2"/>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAkdJUAAAAAA==" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T08:00:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T10:05:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="125" TravelTime="125" Equipment="738" OriginTerminal="3" DestinationTerminal="2"/>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAmdJUAAAAAA==" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T08:00:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T10:10:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="130" TravelTime="130" Equipment="321" OriginTerminal="3" DestinationTerminal="2"/>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAodJUAAAAAA==" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T08:30:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T10:35:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="125" TravelTime="125" Equipment="320" OriginTerminal="1D" DestinationTerminal="1B"/>
              </air:FlightDetailsList>
              <air:AirSegmentList>
                <air:AirSegment Key="2ifpNy4R2BKALdJUAAAAAA==" Group="0" Carrier="AI" FlightNumber="349" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T03:50:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T05:55:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="125" TravelTime="125" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="788" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail used" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="S" AvailabilityDisplayType="General">
                  <air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G">
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Business" BookingCounts="C4|D4|J4|Z4"/>
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="Y9|B9|M9|H9|K9|Q9|V9|W9|G9|L9|U9|T9|S9|E9|NC"/>
                  </air:AirAvailInfo>
                  <air:FlightDetailsRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAKdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                </air:AirSegment>
                <air:AirSegment Key="2ifpNy4R2BKANdJUAAAAAA==" Group="0" Carrier="6E" FlightNumber="171" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T05:10:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T07:20:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="130" TravelTime="130" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="320" ChangeOfPlane="false" PolledAvailabilityOption="No polled avail exists" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="A" AvailabilityDisplayType="General">
                  <air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G">
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="S |Y |Q |N |X |L "/>
                  </air:AirAvailInfo>
                  <air:FlightDetailsRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAMdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                </air:AirSegment>
                <air:AirSegment Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAPdJUAAAAAA==" Group="0" Carrier="SQ" FlightNumber="4747" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T05:55:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T08:05:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="130" TravelTime="130" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="320" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail used" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="S" AvailabilityDisplayType="General" OperationalStatus="Flight Canceled">
                  <air:CodeshareInfo OperatingCarrier="UK" OperatingFlightNumber="975">VISTARA</air:CodeshareInfo>
                  <air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G">
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Business" BookingCounts="ZR|CR|JR|UR|DR|IR"/>
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="PremiumEconomy" BookingCounts="SR|TR|PR"/>
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="YR|BR|ER|MR|HR|WR|NR|QR|KR|VR|GR|LR|XR"/>
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="First" BookingCounts="AR|FR|OR"/>
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="PremiumFirst" BookingCounts="RR"/>
                  </air:AirAvailInfo>
                  <air:FlightDetailsRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAOdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                </air:AirSegment>
                <air:AirSegment Key="2ifpNy4R2BKARdJUAAAAAA==" Group="0" Carrier="UK" FlightNumber="975" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T06:00:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T08:05:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="125" TravelTime="125" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="320" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail used" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="S" AvailabilityDisplayType="General">
                  <air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G">
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Business" BookingCounts="C4|J4|D4|Z3|I2"/>
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="PremiumEconomy" BookingCounts="S9|R9|T9|P9|U9"/>
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="Y9|B9|M9|A9|H9|N9|L9|K9|W9|QC|VC|EC|X4|OC"/>
                  </air:AirAvailInfo>
                  <air:FlightDetailsRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAQdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                </air:AirSegment>
                <air:AirSegment Key="2ifpNy4R2BKATdJUAAAAAA==" Group="0" Carrier="6E" FlightNumber="993" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T06:30:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T08:35:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="125" TravelTime="125" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="320" ChangeOfPlane="false" PolledAvailabilityOption="No polled avail exists" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="A" AvailabilityDisplayType="General">
                  <air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G">
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="S |Y |Q |N |X |L "/>
                  </air:AirAvailInfo>
                  <air:FlightDetailsRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKASdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                </air:AirSegment>
                <air:AirSegment Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAVdJUAAAAAA==" Group="0" Carrier="H1" FlightNumber="9062" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T06:35:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T08:45:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="130" TravelTime="130" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="737" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail used" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="S" AvailabilityDisplayType="General">
                  <air:CodeshareInfo OperatingCarrier="SG">SPICEJET</air:CodeshareInfo>
                  <air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G">
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="YC|MC|NC|QC|VC|OC|GC|RC|UC|TC|LC"/>
                  </air:AirAvailInfo>
                  <air:FlightDetailsRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAUdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                </air:AirSegment>
                <air:AirSegment Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAXdJUAAAAAA==" Group="0" Carrier="AI" FlightNumber="887" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T07:00:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T09:05:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="125" TravelTime="125" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="321" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail used" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="S" AvailabilityDisplayType="General">
                  <air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G">
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="First" BookingCounts="F4|A4"/>
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Business" BookingCounts="C4|D4|J4|Z4"/>
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="Y9|B9|M9|H9|K9|Q9|V9|W9|G9|L9|U9|T9|S9|EC|NC"/>
                  </air:AirAvailInfo>
                  <air:FlightDetailsRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAWdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                </air:AirSegment>
                <air:AirSegment Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAZdJUAAAAAA==" Group="0" Carrier="EY" FlightNumber="8765" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T07:05:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T09:10:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="125" TravelTime="125" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="739" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail used" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="S" AvailabilityDisplayType="General">
                  <air:CodeshareInfo OperatingCarrier="9W" OperatingFlightNumber="332">JET AIRWAYS  INDIA  LTD</air:CodeshareInfo>
                  <air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G">
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Business" BookingCounts="J2|C2|D2|W0|Z0"/>
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="Y4|B4|H4|K4|M4|Q4|L4|V0|U0|E0|T0"/>
                  </air:AirAvailInfo>
                  <air:FlightDetailsRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAYdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                </air:AirSegment>
                <air:AirSegment Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAbdJUAAAAAA==" Group="0" Carrier="9W" FlightNumber="332" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T07:05:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T09:10:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="125" TravelTime="125" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="739" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail used" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="S" AvailabilityDisplayType="General">
                  <air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G">
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Business" BookingCounts="C7|J5|Z6|I6|P6|D2"/>
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="Y7|M7|T7|U7|N7|L7|Q7|S7|K7|H0|V0|O0|W0|G0|B0|X6|E2"/>
                  </air:AirAvailInfo>
                  <air:FlightDetailsRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAadJUAAAAAA=="/>
                </air:AirSegment>
                <air:AirSegment Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAddJUAAAAAA==" Group="0" Carrier="6E" FlightNumber="167" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T07:30:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T09:35:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="125" TravelTime="125" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="320" ChangeOfPlane="false" PolledAvailabilityOption="No polled avail exists" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="A" AvailabilityDisplayType="General">
                  <air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G">
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="S |Y |Q |N |X |L "/>
                  </air:AirAvailInfo>
                  <air:FlightDetailsRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAcdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                </air:AirSegment>
                <air:AirSegment Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAfdJUAAAAAA==" Group="0" Carrier="SQ" FlightNumber="4741" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T07:30:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T09:45:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="135" TravelTime="135" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="320" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail used" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="S" AvailabilityDisplayType="General" OperationalStatus="Flight Canceled">
                  <air:CodeshareInfo OperatingCarrier="UK" OperatingFlightNumber="943">VISTARA</air:CodeshareInfo>
                  <air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G">
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Business" BookingCounts="ZR|CR|JR|UR|DR|IR"/>
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="PremiumEconomy" BookingCounts="SR|TR|PR"/>
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="YR|BR|ER|MR|HR|WR|NR|QR|KR|VR|GR|LR|XR"/>
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="First" BookingCounts="AR|FR|OR"/>
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="PremiumFirst" BookingCounts="RR"/>
                  </air:AirAvailInfo>
                  <air:FlightDetailsRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAedJUAAAAAA=="/>
                </air:AirSegment>
                <air:AirSegment Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAhdJUAAAAAA==" Group="0" Carrier="UK" FlightNumber="943" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T07:30:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T09:45:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="135" TravelTime="135" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="320" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail used" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="S" AvailabilityDisplayType="General">
                  <air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G">
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Business" BookingCounts="C4|J4|D4|Z3|I2"/>
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="PremiumEconomy" BookingCounts="S9|R9|T9|P9|U9"/>
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="Y9|B9|M9|A9|H9|N9|L9|K9|W9|QC|VC|EC|X4|OC"/>
                  </air:AirAvailInfo>
                  <air:FlightDetailsRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAgdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                </air:AirSegment>
                <air:AirSegment Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAjdJUAAAAAA==" Group="0" Carrier="EY" FlightNumber="8768" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T08:00:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T10:05:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="125" TravelTime="125" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="738" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail used" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="S" AvailabilityDisplayType="General">
                  <air:CodeshareInfo OperatingCarrier="9W" OperatingFlightNumber="336">JET AIRWAYS  INDIA  LTD</air:CodeshareInfo>
                  <air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G">
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Business" BookingCounts="J2|C0|D0|W0|Z0"/>
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="Y4|B4|H4|K4|M4|Q4|L4|V0|U0|E0|T0"/>
                  </air:AirAvailInfo>
                  <air:FlightDetailsRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAidJUAAAAAA=="/>
                </air:AirSegment>
                <air:AirSegment Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAldJUAAAAAA==" Group="0" Carrier="9W" FlightNumber="336" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T08:00:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T10:05:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="125" TravelTime="125" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="738" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail used" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="S" AvailabilityDisplayType="General">
                  <air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G">
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Business" BookingCounts="C7|J3|Z2|I2|P2|D2"/>
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="Y7|M7|T7|U7|N7|L7|Q7|S7|K7|H0|V0|O0|W0|G0|B0|X4|E2"/>
                  </air:AirAvailInfo>
                  <air:FlightDetailsRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAkdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                </air:AirSegment>
                <air:AirSegment Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAndJUAAAAAA==" Group="0" Carrier="AI" FlightNumber="665" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T08:00:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T10:10:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="130" TravelTime="130" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="321" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail used" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="S" AvailabilityDisplayType="General">
                  <air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G">
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Business" BookingCounts="C4|D4|J4|Z4"/>
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="Y9|B9|M9|H9|K9|Q9|V9|W9|G9|L9|U9|T9|S4|E9|NC"/>
                  </air:AirAvailInfo>
                  <air:FlightDetailsRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAmdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                </air:AirSegment>
                <air:AirSegment Key="2ifpNy4R2BKApdJUAAAAAA==" Group="0" Carrier="6E" FlightNumber="179" Origin="DEL" Destination="BOM" DepartureTime="2017-06-12T08:30:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2017-06-12T10:35:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="125" TravelTime="125" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="320" ChangeOfPlane="false" PolledAvailabilityOption="No polled avail exists" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="A" AvailabilityDisplayType="General">
                  <air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G">
                    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="S |Y |Q |N |X |L "/>
                  </air:AirAvailInfo>
                  <air:FlightDetailsRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAodJUAAAAAA=="/>
                </air:AirSegment>
              </air:AirSegmentList>
              <air:AirItinerarySolution Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAqdJUAAAAAA==">
                <air:AirSegmentRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKALdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                <air:AirSegmentRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKANdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                <air:AirSegmentRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAPdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                <air:AirSegmentRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKARdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                <air:AirSegmentRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKATdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                <air:AirSegmentRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAVdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                <air:AirSegmentRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAXdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                <air:AirSegmentRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAZdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                <air:AirSegmentRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAbdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                <air:AirSegmentRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAddJUAAAAAA=="/>
                <air:AirSegmentRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAfdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                <air:AirSegmentRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAhdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                <air:AirSegmentRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAjdJUAAAAAA=="/>
                <air:AirSegmentRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAldJUAAAAAA=="/>
                <air:AirSegmentRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKAndJUAAAAAA=="/>
                <air:AirSegmentRef Key="2ifpNy4R2BKApdJUAAAAAA=="/>
              </air:AirItinerarySolution>
            </air:AvailabilitySearchRsp>
          </SOAP:Body>
        </SOAP:Envelope>


Thanks,
Ali
```

Comment: You can use this link to convert XML to Json http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/

Comment: I can't use online tool. Because I am running an API which generates soap xml file. And I want to use that xml file to display the data. I don't have much experience in xml file so wanted to convert it in to json. So, I can handle that output.

Comment: you can write looping based on your XML to create JSON format.

Comment: @Santosh : how can i do that ? I have attached my xml file. And API response creates XML file in which I don't want to disturb that code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP convert XML to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830599/php-convert-xml-to-json)

Comment: @AlexanderTsvetkov : this is not working in my case

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve tag attributes, this is what I would do:

Install: http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer/ (note XML_Serializer is in beta)

```
// INITIALIZE
$unserializer = new XML_Unserializer();
// SET OPTIONS
$unserializer->setOption('complextType', 'array');
$unserializer->setOption('parseAttributes', true);
$unserializer->setOption('prependAttributes', '@');
// UNSERIALIZE   
$unserializer->unserialize($xml);
// ARRAY DATA
$arr = $unserializer->getUnserializedData();
// JSON ENCODE ARRAY
$json = json_encode($arr);
```