# Converting External XML feed to JSON

Tags: php

I am trying to convert an xml feed to json, but using this code it fails to do anything. Any ideas?

```
<?php
$xml_string = 'https://xml.betfred.com/Horse-Racing-Daily.xml';

//read the XML file
$xml = file_get_contents($xml_string);



//encode the formatted data
$json = json_encode();

//generate the JSON file
header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: Right now you are not encoding anything at all? `$json = json_encode($xml)`?

Comment: What are you encoding in `$json = json_encode();` ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830599/php-convert-xml-to-json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP convert XML to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830599/php-convert-xml-to-json)

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19391553/4421474

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put `$xml` in the `json_encode()` method as parameter. Adjust your code like this:

```
$json = json_encode($xml);
```

this will however only convert the `$xml` string to json and that is probably not what you want.

To get close to what you are trying to do you could do:

```
$simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$json = json_encode($simpleXml);
```

Your json might contain alot of junk, but maybe it will be enough for your needs.