# How to convert this response xml to json

Tags: php, json, xml, laravel

I have xml response like this
[image]
I want to change to response json like this

```
{
    "data": {
        "tanggal": "20191015",
        "jam": "103346",
        "BeneficiaryAccount": "12340097034787"
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP convert XML to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830599/php-convert-xml-to-json)

Comment: Please use "simplexml_load_string". follow this link https://howchoo.com/g/yzg1othjmmv/converting-xml-to-json-in-php

Comment: Good practice at SO is to display desired input/output as text not as image.

Comment: I have try the solution but get erro :
simplexml_load_string(): namespace warning : xmlns: URI iBSMWebService_Rem is not absolute

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To convert XML data to JSON:

```
$xml_data = @simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
$json_data = json_encode($xml_data);
$array = json_decode($json_data, TRUE);
```

This would work.

Comment: What's `$xml`? Did you mean `$xml_data`? If you meant `$xml_data`, how does this transform to the OP's desired output?

Comment: i have try this solution but i get the eror
simplexml_load_string(): namespace warning : xmlns: URI iBSMWebService_Rem is not absolute

Comment: @brinardi I have updated the answer again, by solving the error that you are facing, try this

Comment: @PrathameshDoke it still doesnt show how convert the soap response to the json format the OP is asking for.