# How to convert Soap xml response return by the Amadeus Flight Search API to json

Tags: php, json, xml, soap, amadeus

I would like to convert the SOAP XML response into the JSON format. Can anybody please help!

I got below SOAP XML in $response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:awsse="http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/Session_v3" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsa:To>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:To>
    <wsa:From>
        <wsa:Address>https://nodeD2.test.webservices.amadeus.com/XXXXXXXX</wsa:Address>
    </wsa:From>
    <wsa:Action>http://webservices.amadeus.com/FMPTBQ_18_1_1A
    </wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:a4844bc6-2e05-e8e4-b589-6f813ecad262</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:RelatesTo RelationshipType="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/reply">urn:uuid:ac1c8436-ecaf-4bbb-a9ff-11b466dffe18</wsa:RelatesTo>
    <awsse:Session TransactionStatusCode="End"><awsse:SessionId>00896YTRZQPQ</awsse:SessionId><awsse:SequenceNumber>1</awsse:SequenceNumber><awsse:SecurityToken>TRFTGYNBHUYKIOL</awsse:SecurityToken></awsse:Session>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <Fare_MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchReply xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/FMPTBR_18_1_1A">
        <replyStatus><status><advisoryTypeInfo>FQX</advisoryTypeInfo></status></replyStatus>
        <conversionRate><conversionRateDetail><currency>USD</currency></conversionRateDetail></conversionRate>
        <familyInformation><refNumber>1</refNumber><fareFamilyname>BAGSEAT</fareFamilyname><description>OPTIMA</description><carrier>IB</carrier><services><reference>1</reference><status>CHA</status></services><services><reference>2</reference><status>CHA</status></services><services><reference>3</reference><status>INC</status></services><services><reference>4</reference><status>NOF</status></services><services><reference>5</reference><status>NOF</status></services><services><reference>6</reference><status>NOF</status></services><services><reference>7</reference><status>NOF</status></services></familyInformation>
    </Fare_MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchReply>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried this.

```
$xml = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($response)), true);
print '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP convert XML to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830599/php-convert-xml-to-json)

Comment: shameer, please first search in the questions whether you can get the answers from that or not. otherwise it may be a duplicate question and your reputation may decrease

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: I tried all the solution, nothing working

Comment: @SameerAnsari what exactly doesn't work? Can you provide errors you got or comparison of actual result with expected? Be more specific, we don't have access to your environment and thoughts.

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution to the problem, working fine

```
$response  = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $response);
$response  = simplexml_load_string($response);
$dataArray = json_decode(json_encode((array)$response), TRUE);

echo '<pre>';print_r($dataArray);echo '</pre>';die(__FILE__.' On this line '.__LINE__);
```