# Extract value from soap response

Tags: php, arrays, xml, soap

I need help to extract value from a soap response.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/djv5y.jpg

What i exactly need is:
$username=user
$message=success

Comment: the response is the following[1]?  What does this mean

Comment: thank you for response me :), What i exactly need is: $username=user $message=success

Answer (score 0):

Maybe include the SOAP response here, that would be helpful for those who come in the future. As for your question are you using a particular language? That would make it easier to answer.

If you are looking for a way to view use can use this URL: https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer

Answer (score 0):

Ok now that I see it, it's fairly easy

Assuming you have loaded the SOAP XML into a variable, lets call it $xml_string

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string); // Load it as an object
$xmlarray = json_decode(json_encode($xml),TRUE); // Change it into an array
```

Then the variables you are looking for is in

```
 $username = $xmlarray['UserName'];
 $message = $xmlarray['response']['MESSAGE'];
```

BTW This solution is found here
[PHP convert XML to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830599/php-convert-xml-to-json)

I did it as an array as sometimes objects are a little hard to process.  You can easily just do the first line and address it as an object. (If those are the only variables you need then an array works fine. Ex: the 'Plan' data will be messed up in an array as it appears twice)

There can be some issues such as the MESSAGE not appearing or the XML returning a failure but I think you should know how to code around missing datum.