# PHP: How to force simplexml to use certain datatype for a node

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

How can one enforce simplexml_load_string( ) to use same data structure at each node point.

```
$xml = "
<level1>
  <level2>
    <level3>Hello</level3>
    <level3>stackoverflow</level3>
  </level2>
  <level2>
    <level3>My problem</level3>
  </level2>
</level1>";

$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xml)
var_dump($xmlObj);
```

Examining the output,

`level1` is an object; `level2` is an array; `level2[0]` is an array.

`level2[1]` is an object, because there's only one child node, which I'll rather have as a single index array.

I'm collecting the xml from user, and there may be 1 or more nodes inside each `level2`. My sanitisation block is a foreach loop which fails when there's only one node inside `level2`.

The sanitation block looks something like this

```
foreach($xmlObj -> level2 as $lvl2){
  if($lvl2 -> level3[0] == 'condition'){ doSomething( ); }
}
```

`doSomething()` works fine when `<level2>` always has more than one child node in the xml string. If `<level2>`  has only one child `<level3>` node,  an error about trying to get attribute of a non-object comes up.

var_dump shows that the data type changes from object to array depending on how many nodes are nested within.

I'll prefer a way to ensure `<level2>` to always be an array regardless of how many children are within. That saves me from editing too much. But any other way out would suffice.

Thanks

Comment: Ignore the output of `var_dump` as this doesn't show the object hierarchy fully.  If you add your code and show there the problem is then it should be easy enough to fix.

Comment: how are you checking level 2?, you should include that in your post too. that `var_dump` and or `print_r` is sometimes misleading

Comment: Aren't you looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830599/php-convert-xml-to-json

Comment: @Rolf why would he want to convert it to JSON?

Comment: That's why I'm asking. Just thinking a bit out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an information available in the XML itself. So you will have to add it in your implementation. SimpleXML provides both list and item access to a child elements. If you access it as a list (for example with foreach) it will provide all matching child elements.

```
$xml = "
<level1>
  <level2>
    <level3>Hello</level3>
    <level3>stackoverflow</level3>
  </level2>
  <level2>
    <level3>My problem</level3>
  </level2>
</level1>";

$level1 = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$result = [];
foreach($level1->level2 as $level2) {
    $data2 = [];
    foreach ($level2->level3 as $level3) {
        $data2[] = (string)$level3;
    }
    $result[] = $data2;
}

var_dump($result);
```

So the trick is to use the SimpleXMLElement instance directly and not convert it into an array. Do not treat the creation of your JSON structure as a generic conversion. Build up a specific output while reading the XML using SimpleXML.