# Need a function for wp all export to unserialize data of a specific field

Tags: php, xml, serialization, woocommerce, wpallimport

Ι need a function to unserialize  data of a specific field to export to XML File.

My serialize field is

```
<B2B_Sale_price><![CDATA[a:1:{i:6704;a:2:{s:13:"regular_price";s:8:"17.33871";s:10:"sale_price";s:5:"13.77";}}]]></B2B_Sale_price>
```

and i'd like to export only the sale_price.

This function works perfect for csv export

```
function data_deserialize_csv($value){$output = '';$data = unserialize($value);print_r($data);$data = reset($data);return $data['sale_price'];}
```

But for xml return an error
PHP Error: reset() expects parameter 1 to be array, bool given on line 15 of the Functions Editor

Answer (score 1):

You can use a version of the [code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19391553/231316) to go from XML to JSON, and then to an array.

```php
function data_deserialize_xml($value)
{
    // Parse as XML, treating the CDATA as content
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($value, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    
    // Convert back and forth
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    
    // Grab the first item
    $value = reset($array);
    
    // Same code as before
    $data = unserialize($value);
    print_r($data);
    $data = reset($data);
    return $data['sale_price'];
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, respond with an error again in line $data = reset($data); PHP Error: reset() expects parameter 1 to be array, bool given