# Convert TYPO3 locallang values into json file

Tags: php, typo3

I have created plugin and I have used locallang for labels.
I am working on TYPO3 10 and I have used many locallang values in my template file for labels.

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\LocalizationUtility::translate('your_label_key','your_extensionName');
```

I tried this code it works fine, but it is only for one key or label.

I want all the translation in json formant (json file), is there any way to do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some code? What code can you share that you attempted?

Comment: \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\LocalizationUtility::translate('your_label_key','your_extensionName');

Comment: I tried this and it gives right result, but only for one label I want all labels in the locallang.xlf file, Because I have 100+ labels in locallang file.

Comment: Please edit it into the question as a minimal self contained example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in another way.

It look like below,

```
    $fileContents= file_get_contents($url);
    $fileContents = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $fileContents);
    $fileContents = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $fileContents));
    $simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);
    $json = json_encode($simpleXml);
```

First i store my locallang file into variable with file_get_contents($url);

Then with json_encode($xml),
All locallang values converted into json format.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830599/php-convert-xml-to-json
-referred this question